# change div with background image to color ackground with transition left

Tags: html, css, hover, transition

So I have this img that I use as the background of the navbar li and I want that on :hover the img will have red overlay color - and I want it to have a transition where the color change is coming from the right to the left

This is the img I'm using [nav li img](http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/6739/0bsf.png)
so plz notice that the img is a png that have some transperen spaces in it..

I've tried searching an answer but I could only find fade transitions...

Comment: are you limited only using css3? is jquery a possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final pen is [here](http://codepen.io/aktuna/pen/Jgyve).

I did use css masks and it's especially interesting to see that, using masks are very simple with chrome than firefox. The code will work at both firefox and chrome, i didn't check for ie..

[Here](http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking) there is a great tutorial on css masks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [demo](http://codepen.io/aktuna/pen/eIaEh), please.

This is a pure css solution.

(I added blue background for png to show transparent space)

Comment: This is kinda what I want only I dont want the red to effect the transperent parts of the img...

Comment: Maybe u can use a `z-index: -1;` to `.overlay` class. But the problem is, if u don't want to take effect to transparent parts, you have to make them opaque, not transparent, in this code ;)

Comment: making it opaque won't work for me because there's an image slideshow going on behind this nav... If i had an image that is the same in terms of shape and transparency and i had it Colored red, would it be easier to get the effect i look for?

Comment: Is this ok? The transition will be between 325px and 75px. Change this: `.container:hover .overlay {
  left:75px;  
}`